# Where can I buy the chess engine Komodo? Do I get somekind of bonus premium membership with it? And when will its next version be released?

Tags: engines, software

I have three questions about the chess engine Komodo.

Firstly, where can I buy and order it? I would like to have it in a CD (not just download it). I went into the website of a chess store near where I live (Paris), but it apparently does not sell Komodo (but it sells Fritz, Houdini, Hiarcs, Junior, Rybka and Shredder).

Secondly, do I get a "bonus" with Komodo? When I bought Fritz and Houdini I got a bonus of one year premium membership into a chess server called "Playchess". Do I also get something like that with Komodo?

Thirdly, does anyone know when will the next version of Komodo be released approximately? Because if the version 8 gets released soon, then there's no point in buying the version 7 today.

I found the release dates of all the previous versions of Komodo:

- Version 4: December 2011
- Version 5: June 2013
- Version 6: October 2013
- Version TCEC: December 2013
- Version 7: May 2014

So it seems the version 8 will be released very approximately in November..

Comment: You have the habbit of posting engine-related but dubious questions. In this case, it's a support question to Komodo team. -1

Comment: I agree with member *Student T*, this question indeed is more suitable for the Komodo team. -1

Comment: I don't really see why my questions are "dubious"... Except maybe for the third question, I believe all of them can be answered just by normal people who have bought Komodo... Anyway, how and where should I ask again this question to this "Komodo team" that you recommended me?

Comment: Send an email to Komodo. Mark.L, the developer for Komodo will answer you.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase Komodo 7 on ICC and get one month subscription to ICC free here:
https://store.chessclub.com/komodo-7

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the bonus subscription to ICC lasts only one single month? This seems very little. I had found this article http://susanpolgar.blogspot.fr/2014/01/komodo-worlds-strongest-chess-engine-3.html which said the subscription to ICC lasted 3 months (but that offer expired February 1 2014). And even more importantly: are you sure the link you've given offers Komodo in a physical CD? I don't want to just download it...

Comment: The link definitely gives you just a download.

Comment: Ah yes, Its a download only link. Not sure where you might be able to get the CD shipped along with an online subscription free though!